# PHP Code Keeps Creating Another Row With Every Run Of Code

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Whenever the code below is run the right row is made in the right places in the table but then it makes an extra row with the username blank but the password with this md5 `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` which is blank as well.

The code:

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "will");
define("DB_PASS", "blahblah");
define("DB_NAME", "blah");
define("TBL_USERS", "users");

function addNewUser($username, $password){
   global $connection;
   $password1 = md5($password);
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
   return mysql_query($q, $connection);
}    

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
addNewUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
}
```

How do I stop it from doing this? That code is run in a php script by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a guess - it might be trying to run the query once on your "return" line within the function, and then again when on your actual call line (addNewUsers).

Try this:

```
function addNewUser($username, $password){
   $password1 = md5($password);
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
   return $q;
}    

$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query(addNewUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]), $connection);
```

Comment: If he isn't running a query in the function, would he still need the global connection variable?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function is being called without the POST variables being set (because that hash corresponds to an empty string).  Is your code trying to add a user while the form is being displayed?  If so, make sure both the username and password aren't empty before adding the user..

Like:

```
function addNewUser($username, $password){
   global $connection;
   if (empty($username) || empty($password))
      return;
   $password1 = md5($password);
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
   $q = "INSERT INTO ".TBL_USERS." VALUES ('$username', '$password1')";
   return mysql_query($q, $connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should build in a if statement around your function call.
Try something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["send"]))
{
  addNewUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
}
```

$_POST["send"] will be set when submitting a form.

If you do not work with a form you can check the username and password for being set:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{
addNewUser($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
}
```

I hope it will work!

Greetings,
Mixxiphoid